# Как оптимизировать запрос MySQL где 6млн строк?

Tags: python, mysql

Есть вот такая таблица MySQL которая включает в себя 8 столбцов и имеет 6млн строк.
[image: Таблица]

На user_id стоит индекс, поиск по user_id вопросов не вызывает. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать рандомную выборку 1 строки по условиям: sex, city, age

SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE city='' and sex='' and age IN ('', '', '',..) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

Я много раз изменял запрос, но наиболее быстрый получился этот. Время запроса составляет в районе 15-20 секунд, что очень много.  Как можно оптимизировать запрос, бд, таблицу для достижения 1-3 секунд для ответа?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133351/discussion-on-question-by-pharci----mysql--6-).

Comment: Я попробовал разные запросы, и оказалось что при запросе с диапазоном between не используется ключ, ответы в консоли я прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Я могу зайти в чат, но я не могу там писать т.к. не хватает баллов репутации. Время выполнение с точным возрастом меньше на +-3 секунды. А поле city типа VARCHAR

Comment: Теперь я могу писать в чате, думаю нам стоит перейти туда

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось. Я использовал такую структуру ([тут](https://gist.github.com/romank0/74a49d44f637de5a9df32e690765320b) полный текст):

```
create table t (
    user_id int,
    username text,
    surname text,
    age int,
    aboutme text,
    sex bool,
    city int
);
```

Обратите внимание, тут изменены типы полей (в первоначальном варианте были текстовыми), чтобы уменьшить размер ключа и размер индекса:

1. sex типа `bool`
2. city - `int`, это должен быть внешний ключ на таблицу с городами

С такими индексами:

```
create unique index t_user_id_idx on t(user_id);
create index t2_idx on t(city, sex, age, user_id);
```

результат:

```
 SELECT user_id FROM t WHERE city=1 and sex=false and age between 1 and 3 order by rand() limit 1;
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| 2230071 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.45 sec)
```

И план:

```
explain SELECT user_id FROM t WHERE city=1 and sex=false and age between 1 and 3 order by rand() limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | range | t2_idx        | t2_idx | 12      | NULL | 991602 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Изначально время выполнения было 40 секунд (я запускал в докере, а там с диском работа медленней).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: а `user_id`  во втором индексе какой смысл имеет?

Comment: @teran Без поля `user_id` в индексе такой индекс для данного запроса не используется и время выполнения запроса те же 40 секунд. По всему выходит, что mysql в таком случае находит нужные записи в индексе и делает сортировку используя только сам индекс, где уже есть user_id. Если использовать не between, а только `=`, то индекс используется, но время выполнения с таким индексом 10 секунд.

Comment: @teran Так он же становится покрывающим...

Comment: *Я использовал такую структуру* Плохая структура. В ней отсутствует явный первичный ключ. И я настоятельно рекомендую сделать таковым индекс по `(user_id)`. Во-первых, он всё равно уникальный, во-вторых, он всё равно будет использоваться как кластерный. А дополнительное ограничение на поле `user_id int NOT NULL` ничего не попортит.

Comment: @Akina ясна. в sql server оно в inlclude определяется, не сообразил сразу

Comment: Все правильно, но для рассматриваемой задачи ключ  роли не играет, это же демонстрация. У ТС ПК есть и он его явно не удалит. Я не создавал индексов при создании таблиц, только для того, чтоб генерация данных была быстрей.